# How to add content and add color to it using css only

Tags: html, css

I have below HTML code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to select only elements with attrbute-name="true" and modify its `Item` as `Item my-text-in-greencolor`. So here I want to add some custom text with green color.

Is there a way to do this using only CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
    [attribute-name="true"] {
      background-color: green;
    }

    [attribute-name="true"] td:nth-child(1):after {
      content: ' my-text-in-greencolor';
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you are:

```
[attribute-name="true"] {
  background-color: green;
}

[attribute-name="true"] td:nth-child(1):after {
  content: ' my-text-in-greencolor';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/azmgy2h7/

Answer (score 2):

You can just call it in CSS and change color to green if its true.

```css
[attribute-name="true"] {
  color: green;
}

[attribute-name="true"] td:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: " is true";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to add text also like `Item is true` instead of just `Item` for true items

Comment: Alright I've edited answer, basically you'll need to add an after rule for the first td, thus you use `nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```css
[attribute-name="true"] td:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

[attribute-name="true"] td:first-child::after {
  content: ' is true';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="false">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr attribute-name="true">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'attribute selector' --

```
tr[atribute-name="true"] { 
  color: green;
}
```

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: I want to add text also like Item is true instead of just Item for true items

Comment: You're looking for pseudo-elements, and the `content` tag-- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

CSS can insert text content before or after an element. To specify this, make a rule and add ::before or ::after to the selector. In the declaration, specify the content property with the text content as its value.

**HTML**

A text where I need to `<span class="ref">something</span>`

**CSS**

```
.ref::before { 
     font-weight: bold;
     color: navy;
     content: "Reference "; 
}
```

**Output**

> A text where I need to **Reference** something

To set the text from first `td` after the attribute green you can do.

```
tr[attribute-name="true"] > td {
     color:green;
}

tr[attribute-name="true"] > td:nth-child(1):after { 
     content: ' my-text-in-greencolor'; 
}
```